# gulp 4 version problem causes all tasks to fail

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-4

gulp decided it had enough and it died in my project.

current version

```
gulp -v
[11:26:35] CLI version 3.9.1
[11:26:35] Local version 4.0.0
```

if i run one of the tasks that worked yesterday I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129
>       gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
>                      ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

now I have seen this error all over the place and tried many things to fix it

1. clear node_module and install with rm -rf node_modules and npm i
2. - uninstall gulp and gulp-cli from both the global and local packages
   - after which I only installed gulp-cli globally and gulp v4 locally in dev
3. close everything and restart computer hoping for a magic fix, no luck

### EDIT:

also tried the following with no success

4. delete package-lock.json to force recreate
5. install gulp globally

### what does work

There seems to be some issue where the cli version is not being used properly.
If i explicitly use the gulp file from my projects local node_modules folder like this:

```
node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js my-task
```

then the **my-task** will run and work correctly

### what does NOT work

if i use the following command:

```
gulp my-task
```

I get the error quoted at the top of this post.

I am not sure where to go from here, I have a workaround but can not figure out why gulp is dying on me when I am trying to use the latest stable version of both gulp and the cli.

Comment: `gulp-cli` is some npm module that lets you run gulp command line commands from Node? I think you need to install gulp globally. You say you only installed gulp-cli globally, which doesn't seem relevant if I'm understanding your problem. try `npm install -g gulp` and doing it again

Comment: oh I don't think I misunderstood. looks like gulp comes with gulp-cli (it's a dependency), and that's ultimately what's used when running from command line. Maybe my suggestion won't work though I've seen it work before for this issue

Comment: @pushkin adding gulp globally did not solve the issue, thanks

Comment: maybe you've tried everything here, but [here](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-sips-command-line-interface-e53411d4467)

Answer (score 3):

I just recently upgraded from Gulp 3 to 4, and had a very similar problem (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'task' of undefined`). Apparently, this was caused by a change in the `task` method, which (in version 3) would return a reference to the `gulp` object itself after defining a task, but now (in version 4) returns [nothing](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task), thus causing this error when one tries to chain tasks fluently.

The fix for me was to recreate my gulpfile [using exports instead](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks).

Since you didn't include your gulpfile in the original question, I don't know if this is your issue or not, but since this question came up while I was looking for some pointers on making the leap from v3 to v4, I thought it might be useful to share.